# Python Selenium - search item code in list, check availability, notify if available, repeat with next item code

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am on website tap.dor.ms.gov/_/ and am using selenium python to scrape it. I have a list of item codes that I want the program to run through the search bar, see if the product is in stock and available to buy, then notify me of the availability, and repeat with the other items in the list, but I have nearly no idea how to do that. You do need a login for the site, and we are willing to create a new account for the sole purpose of receiving help. Thank you.

'''python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
from selenium.wedriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import chromedriver_binary
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

#Open web address and print title.
driver.get('https://tap.dor.ms.gov/_/')
print(driver.title)

#Entering username.
username = driver.find_element_by_id("Dd-5")
username.send_keys("fakeusername")

#Entering password.
password = driver.find_element_by_id("Dd-6")
password.send_keys("fakepassword")

#Click login button.
login_button = "Dd-7"

#Ensuring the element exists on the page before we try to click it.
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, login_button))
    )
    element.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#Click favorites tab.
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Favorites")

#Ensuring the element exists on the page before we try to click it.
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Favorites"))
    )
    element.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#Click Add/View Retail Orders.
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add/View Retail Orders")

#Ensuring the element exists on the page before we try to click it.
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Add/View Retail Orders"))
    )
    element.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

add_order_button = "Dc-d"
#Click Add Order button.
#Ensuring the element exists on the page before we try to click it.
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, add_order_button))
    )
    element.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#Find Manually enter items radio button.
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Dl-n"]')

#Ensuring the element exists on the page before we try to click it.
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Dl-n"]'))
    )
    element.click()
except:
    driver.quit()

#Click Next button.
next_button = "action_12"

element = driver.find_element_by_id(next_button)
element.click()

driver.implicity_wait(5)

#List of item codes to be searched.
item_codes = [508350, 611940, 48099, 48101, 48102, 48105, 48106, 48107, 48108, 10802, 10826, 87484, 87485, 89154, 89175, 89200, 47861, 47863, 47865, 47869, 49086, 49182, 49186, 49189, 88290, 88291, 88294, 88296, 88298, 87280, 87288, 88833, 89177]

#Variable for item search bar id.
item_search_bar = "Dm-7"

search = driver.find_element_by_id(item_search_bar)
search.click()

for i in item_codes:
    search.send_keys(i)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The search bar id is "Dm-7".
This is my first program. Please explain plainly. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: please post your code in plain text

Comment: Will do. Just a moment.

Comment: Okay @RJAdriaansen, I hope this is formatted correctly and what you were asking for.

Comment: Please also add imports and the driver definition so we can replicate the issue. Also, when I try to search on the codes manually it doesn't return anything. So I'm not sure what output you expect.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I do not understand what you are saying in the last two sentences, but I have added my imports to the post. Also, I have not typed out my entire program, but only the imports and the part that I am asking for help with.

Comment: You're missing `driver.get('https://tap.dor.ms.gov/_/')`. But what output do you expect from the code? Also, there is no search bar with id `Dm-7`. Does this require a login?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I have driver.get() in the code, just didn't post it here. You do need a login, but I cannot share it. Give me a couple of minutes and I can post the entire code for you. Thank you for the patience you have been showing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I will not be able to replicate the issue if it's behind a login...

Comment: @RJAdriaansen we may be able to create an account with the sole purpose of giving you the ability to replicate the issue.